# this.props.parentprop.map is not a function (TypeError)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having difficulties using the `.map()` method to iterate over the parent's state objects in a child component (ChildOne) to create multiple instances of another child component (ChildTwo).

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listItems: [] // this list 
    }
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <ChildTwo listItems={this.state.listItems} />
       </div>
    }
```

for ChildOne, where the error can be found:

```
class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.items); // returns the array in parent state with no problem
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.items.map(item => { // this.props.items.map is not a function
                    return (
                        <ChildTwo item={item} key={item.id} />
                    )})
                }
            </div>
```

and finally, for ChildTwo:

```
class ChildTwo extends Component {
  render() (
    return (
        <div>
           <ChildOne items={this.props.listItems} />
        </div>
```

Comment: Because of didnt give you proper props in tracklist component there is not listItem variable that was expacting in ChildTwo component also you have another fault that is already explained by @Austin Greco

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is actually in `ChildTwo`? It's very confusing because your classes are not named the same as their rendering (`TrackList`, etc..).

You're rendering it like this, passing two different props named the same both named `item`:

```
<ChildTwo item={item} item={item.id} />
```

But the class definition is looking for a prop named `listItems`

```
class ChildTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    // ChildTwo was rendered with props `item`
    return (
        <div>
           <ChildOne items={this.props.listItems} />
        </div>
```

I would suggest using [`prop-types`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) to show errors when the incorrect props are being passed.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'd first like to apologize that the class `TrackList` is a typo its supposed to be `ChildTwo`. the second `item` prop is also supposed to be `key`. I fixed my question.